# CSS infinite classes .class0, .class1,

Tags: css, class

A JS library I am using is creating a new class every time I switch the page.

Something like:

.marquee0
.marquee1
.marquee2
.marquee3
.marquee4
.marquee5
.marquee6
...

Is there a way I can minify this in my css for an infinite amount of numbers?
At the moment I use this:

```
.marquee0, .marquee1, .marquee2, .marquee3, .marquee4, .marquee5, .marquee6 {

}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way! The CSS [contains selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)

```
div[class*="marquee"] {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

will give all those a background color.

Comment: learnt something new.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! The simple answer I was looking for!